Is neighbour search better than approximate neighbour search?
If I have the following:
200k vectors
Find nearest neighbour among 100 vectors
Should I be just using NN and calculate distance at request time or use a vector database for ANN?
I can hold 200k vectors in memory but I only want to search for nearest from a select amount (n=100) at request time.
Have tried searching for this answer online. Looking up when to use ANN for n values.
